# How can sensitive data written in a custom Outlook Form be protected?

Tags: security, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, encryption, outlook-form

We have an outlook form that is installed on some users machines, for use with their Exchange email account. All the emails sent using that form go to an internal functional/shared mailbox that is shared between a team of users, so each of those users configure the functional/shared mailbox in their Outlook, besides their individual work account.

The form will soon include some fields to enter credit card information, so I'm wondering what are the different options to protect that information.

1. While the outlook form is just an entry mask/program for the email, is the data transmitted in plain-text to the Exchange server?
2. What would be the difference between using DRM to protect the credit card number, vs. encrypting the email using PGP?
3. Are there any other recommended/standard methods to encrypting such information through email?

Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated, thanks!